# How to filter the JSON array object like nested Sql Query using es6 syntax in effective way

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I am new to ES6 syntax, please help me with this.

I have a JSON array like:

```
var data = [{
    "recordid": 1,
    "recordidclass": "Parent Class",
    "relatedrecid": 2,
    "relatedrecclass": "Child Class2"   
},
{
    "recordid": 1,
    "recordidclass": "Parent Class",
    "relatedrecid": 3,
    "relatedrecclass": "Child Class3"   
},
{
    "recordid": 9,
    "recordidclass": "Parent Class",
    "relatedrecid": 14,
    "relatedrecclass": "Child Class4"   
},
{
    "recordid": 2,
    "recordidclass": "Parent Class",
    "relatedrecid": 5,
    "relatedrecclass": "Child Class5"   
},
{
    "recordid": 5,
    "recordidclass": "Parent Class",
    "relatedrecid": 6,
    "relatedrecclass": "Child Class6"   
},
{
    "recordid": 3,
    "recordidclass": "Parent Class",
    "relatedrecid": 7,
    "relatedrecclass": "Child Class7"   
},
{
    "recordid": 4,
    "recordidclass": "Parent Class",
    "relatedrecid": 8,
    "relatedrecclass": "Child Class8"   
},{...}]
```

All the parent and child objects are in same array.
I want to filter the data based on `recordid` and I should get all the object which matches with `recordid` and its `relatedrecid` object as well.

In short, based on the sample data, if I call a `getRequiredData(1)` (which is `recordid`), I should get all the data which matches the `recordid` and its `relatedrecid` data as well.

My output should be:

```
var result = [{
    "recordid": 1,
    "recordidclass": "Parent Class",
    "relatedrecid": 2,
    "relatedrecclass": "Child Class2"   
},
{
    "recordid": 1,
    "recordidclass": "Parent Class",
    "relatedrecid": 3,
    "relatedrecclass": "Child Class3"   
},
{
    "recordid": 2,
    "recordidclass": "Parent Class",
    "relatedrecid": 5,
    "relatedrecclass": "Child Class5"   
},
{
    "recordid": 3,
    "recordidclass": "Parent Class",
    "relatedrecid": 7,
    "relatedrecclass": "Child Class7"   
}]
```

Comment: Show what you have tried using any javascript...regardless of it being es6 or not. Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service

Comment: Welcome to S.O.! Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter but also I have to recommend that you seek to solve your problem with a database query not javascript (... I would probably make a bad algorithm choice if I used javascript for this)

Comment: where is the es6 part? :P

Comment: @Roman: Your edit to improve code formatting was ok, but please make sure you fix everything you can when editing. You missed several grammar and code formatting issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array.find to locate the record with matching id.
Use array.filter to locate records relating to the first one.

Here I have joined the results of those two operations into one array.

```js
var data = [{
    "recordid": 1,
    "recordidclass": "Parent Class",
    "relatedrecid": 2,
    "relatedrecclass": "Child Class2"   
},
{
    "recordid": 1,
    "recordidclass": "Parent Class",
    "relatedrecid": 3,
    "relatedrecclass": "Child Class3"   
},
{
    "recordid": 9,
    "recordidclass": "Parent Class",
    "relatedrecid": 14,
    "relatedrecclass": "Child Class4"   
},
{
    "recordid": 2,
    "recordidclass": "Parent Class",
    "relatedrecid": 5,
    "relatedrecclass": "Child Class5"   
},
{
    "recordid": 5,
    "recordidclass": "Parent Class",
    "relatedrecid": 6,
    "relatedrecclass": "Child Class6"   
},
{
    "recordid": 3,
    "recordidclass": "Parent Class",
    "relatedrecid": 7,
    "relatedrecclass": "Child Class7"   
},
{
    "recordid": 4,
    "recordidclass": "Parent Class",
    "relatedrecid": 8,
    "relatedrecclass": "Child Class8"   
}];


var someId = 1;
var d1 = data.find(e => e.recordid == someId);
var d2 = data.filter(e => e.recordid == d1.relatedrecid);
d2.unshift(d1);
console.log(d2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to utilize a filter on the array. Info on that can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Where you would do `filteredResults = result.filter(function(item){return item.recordId == paramId});`

Or good old fashioned for loop never fails.

And as Roman points out, es6 syntax lets you do this:

```
filteredResults = result.filter(item=>item.recordId == paramId);
```

which does the exact same thing, just slightly shorter hand syntax :)

Comment: or the es6-way: filteredResults = result.filter(item => item.recordId == paramId)